# What is the correct syntax for Cloudformation AWS::IAM::Policy for S3 full access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

In a CloudFormation script I create an IAM::Policy that gets applied to a Kinesis Firehose.  It has the following PolicyDocument Statement

```
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - 's3:AbortMultipartUpload'
      - 's3:GetBucketLocation'
      - 's3:GetObject'
      - 's3:ListBucket'
      - 's3:ListBucketMultipartUploads'
      - 's3:PutObject'
    Resource: arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname
```

This comes from the AWS docs.

When I test this with Test Data it does not allow any data through.  If I edit the Policy and add `S3FullAccess` it begins allowing the Test Data through to the S3 bucket.  I've also tried with

`Resource: arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*`

and get the same results.

If I change the CloudFormation script to this

```
Statement:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action: 's3:*'
    Resource: '*'
```

it allows Test Data through.

What's wrong with the first statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These actions operate at the bucket level and require a resource of `arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname`:

- `s3:GetBucketLocation`
- `s3:ListBucket`
- `s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads`

These actions operate at the object level and require a resource of `arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*` (or a particular prefix such as `arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/invoices/*`):

- `s3:AbortMultipartUpload`
- `s3:GetObject`
- `s3:PutObject`

You can figure out whether an action operates at the **Bucket** or **Object** level by reviewing the **Resource Types** column on: [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon S3 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html)

You can either list the actions separately, or combine them with:

```
    Action:
      - 's3:AbortMultipartUpload'
      - 's3:GetBucketLocation'
      - 's3:GetObject'
      - 's3:ListBucket'
      - 's3:ListBucketMultipartUploads'
      - 's3:PutObject'
    Resource:
      - arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname
      - arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can try [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) . It is an online cloudformation template generator.